# Necessity of the anonymous function as wrapper in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wrapper, anonymous-function

Why does this work:

```
$("#oneButton").click(function () {
    alert("hello");
});
```

But this doesn't work?

```
$("#oneButton").click(
    alert("hello");
);
```

Comment: This will help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The anonymous function route gives a function to be *executed later*. The second example merely executes code *immediately*, never waiting for a click event to take place.

The `$.fn.click` method expects to call a function on your behalf, which will handle the future click event(s). If you give it a number, or a string, or `undefined`, it will do nothing.

The `alert` function returns `undefined`, so your second example is nothing more than:

```
$("#oneButton").click(undefined);
```

Note that you don't need to use an anymous function, and in most cases you probably shouldn't. You can use a named function, which helps with debugging down the road:

```
function handle ( event ) {
    alert( "Clicked" );
}

$("#oneButton").click(handle); // or .click(function handle ( event ) { ... });
```

In this example, we're passing the function reference to our click event to serve as the handler. Now that jQuery knows of our function, it will execute it when the click event is raised on `#oneButton`.

Comment: thanks -- is this named function what is referred to as a "callback function"?

Comment: @user1883050 This is a *handler*, meaning it will be executed to handle the click event. Callbacks are typically functions that are executed once an event has completed, like an animation.

Comment: A quick follow up question. You mentioned that the alert function returns undefined. How does one learn that? Is it in the documentation for the alert function? Or is there some other technique available that can tell us what the return value of any function is? Thanks.

Comment: @user1883050 All functions return `undefined`, unless told to do otherwise. See section [13.2.1 of the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1) - special attention to the last step of the `[[Call]]` process: "Otherwise result.type must be normal. Return undefined."